# How to use lower_bound(upper_bound) to find position of any number in array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, lower-bound, upperbound

For example, I have an array with elements 1,7,9,23,34,47,67,89,123,234,345,567.
I need to know the position of 123.

Comment: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) Ought to work just fine. You can subtract `std::begin(array)` to get an (numerical) index rather than an iterator if that's what you need.

Comment: Have you tried anything? please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Xirema with std::find you have the same problem. The function returns that iterator, not the position. So you still have to do the calculation in User_Targaryen's answer.

Comment: @George, I think that the OP provided a complete minimal example (it doesn't look like they've edited it since your comment either).

Comment: @Elliott All I can see is "For example, I have an array with elements 1,7,9,23,34,47,67,89,123,234,345,567. I need to know the position of 123.". The sequence bit doesn't count, it needs to be a code example, a C++ code example really from the tag.

Comment: Together with the title of the question, it seems pretty explicit: std::lower_bound on an array to get the index instead of the element. Sure, the OP's question could be a bit better, but not enough to require revision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare and initialize the array with the elements. Then create a `vector` of ints. Use `upper_bound()` on the `vector`. Here is an example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,7,9,23,34,47,67,89,123,234,345,567};
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    vector<int> v(arr,arr+len);

    vector<int>::iterator upper;
    upper = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 123);
    cout<<(upper-v.begin())<<endl;  // Output: 9

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: You can use `std::upper_bound` and `std::lower_bound` directly on the array. There's no need for that vector.

Comment: `std::upper` returns the first value **greater** than the sought one. If, for instance, you had sought for value 122 you would still get position 9 (or rather, 8), even though the value you looked for wasn't found.

Comment: @Elliott No, it's actually as I wrote it. Have a look: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound

You're thinking of `std::lower_bound` which returns an iterator to either the value you're looking for or the one preceding it.

For both `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` `end()` is returned if no suitable value could be found.